# not able to create Binary search tree in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

My `InsertInTree` function is not working properly, and I am not able to figure out my problem.  Please suggest changes I can make (but I don't want to use recursion).

It takes values from the structure and the function `GetNewNode` returns the node with left and right pointer as `NULL`:

```
public:

void InsertInTree(int piData) 
{
    Node*newNode = NULL;
    newNode=GetNewNode(piData);
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=newNode;
        return;
    }

    Node*temp = root;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(newNode->data<=temp->data)
        {
            temp=temp->left;
        }
        else
        {
            temp=temp->right;
        }

    }

    temp=newNode;
    return;
}
bool SearchNum(int piSearch)
{

    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Node*temp=root;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data==piSearch)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(piSearch<=temp->data)
        {
            temp=temp->left;
        }
        else
        {
            temp=temp->right;
        }

    }
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: and the GetNewNode code is...

Comment: Also, give an example of what it's doing now, and what are you expecting. (`not working properly` could be a lot of things, crashing, working but creates erroneous result) // Help us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming root is global. you should use one more node i.e. *pre (previousnode).

```
*pre=NULL; 

while(temp!=NULL){
   if(newnode->data<=temp->data){
     pre=temp;  
     temp=temp->left;
}else{
     pre=temp;
     temp=temp->right;
  }
}

if(newnode->data<=pre->data)
pre->left=newnode;
else
pre->right=newnode;
```

this will solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix your issue:

```
void InsertInTree(int piData) 
{
    Node* newNode = GetNewNode(piData);
    Node** temp = &root;

    while (*temp != NULL)
    {
        if (newNode->data <= (*temp)->data)
        {
            temp = &(*temp)->left;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = &(*temp)->right;
        }
    }
    *temp = newNode;
}
```